# How your .gitignore for Latex projects looks like?

Tags: git, latex

I am wondering what files I should exclude from VSC in LaTeX projects

Comment: Redirect: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17845/95042

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've looked into `Kile's` (LaTeX editor) preferences and found `Automatically clean-up files` list. I think that it is surely unnecessary files. The List:

```
.aux .bit .blg .bbl .lof .log .lot .glo .glx .gxg .gxs .idx .ilg .ind .out .url .svn .toc
```

I think it is enough for `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/TeX.gitignore) I found quite comprehensive for latex projects.

Also since I have tex file in multiple sub-directories, I remove the `auto` folders in those sub-directories by adding `**/auto/**` to the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

Github provides a good one over [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/TeX.gitignore), I modified theirs slightly because i normally put my latex files in a nested folder in my git repo, so this solves that minor change:

```
## Core latex/pdflatex auxiliary files:
**/*.aux
**/*.lof
**/*.log
**/*.lot
**/*.fls
**/*.out
**/*.toc
**/*.fmt
**/*.fot
**/*.cb
**/*.cb2
**/*.lb
```

and if you use the additional libraries, you can do something similar for them too!